# Check a theorem about the category Set

Tags: category-theory

Please check if the following statement is true:

**Statement** Let $\varphi : X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of the category
$\mathbf{Set}$. Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. Then $\varphi$
can be factored (in a unique way) $\varphi = u \circ \pi$ where $\pi$ is the
projection for this equivalence and $u : (X / \sim) \rightarrow Y$.

Comment: $\varphi$ needs to be constant on equivalence classes for this to hold.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: So I suppose my statement is an erroneous formulation of the UMP for coequalizers in Set. What is the correct formulation?

Comment: I am not sure how to formulate it in category theory terms. If you simply add the assumption that $\varphi$ is constant on equivalence classes, then the result is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is correct , provided that you add that $\varphi$ respects the equivalence,that is: that it is constant on all members of an equivalence class.

You can read about the UMP of coequalizers in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer)